# asp.net Web Method not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asmx, webmethod

I trying call webmethod in my web project. I didnt found a problem in my codes and I called webmethod thousands of times before but I never see mistake like this before. Never enter my methods codes and it return my html page codes to me. ( sorry my bad english :)).. Please someone help me about that.

My Web method codes :

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GirisKontrol(string UserName, string Pass)
    {
        try
        {
            string strSonuc = "";
            var context = new DBEntities();
            var Kisi = context.users.Where(t => t.eposta== UserName  && t.sifre == Pass).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Kisi != null && Kisi.uye_onay==1)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["UyeID"] = Kisi.ID;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Gorev"] = Kisi.gorev;


                return Kisi.adsoyad;
            }
            else
                return "0";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

My javascript codes:

```
 function GirisKontrol() {
            PageMethods.GirisKontrol("asd", "sad", function(a) {
                alert(a);
});
}
```

or I tried this but I got same result:

```
function test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "indexDeneme.aspx/GirisKontrol",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is result and it never go in c# codes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1BLH.png)

Comment: Please look at image. That is web method result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```

Otherwise your method won't have access to the current `SessionState`, and the part where you try to save data to `Session` won't work.

The first example where you call `PageMethods.GirisKontrol` is unclear - your JavaScript isn't going to know about the server-side methods.

The second example using Ajax looks closer, but you're not passing any data.

```
data: "{}",
```

perhaps you mean this:

```
data: "{'UserName': 'asd', 'Pass': 'sad'}",
```